# Dependencies of several maven projects within git

Tags: git, maven

I have a Git repository, that is used by several people, with several Maven projects in it. Some of them might depend on each other.

How can I add these projects (which others depend on) automatically to an local maven repository, so that the dependencies are instantly available for every user who checks out the git repository (as well as for the continuous integration server)?

Would a local maven repository inside the git repository be recommended? If so how can I add new and updated projects automatically to that repository?

Comment: Why not use a maven repository manager, such as Nexus?

Comment: Can Nexus automatically checkout the git repo and add/update the projects?

Comment: Ideally you will be deploying snapshot versions via your CI infrastructure for each project you have. Nexus is a place to host the artifacts, not build them. That is what your CI software is for.

Comment: I recommend reading http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html

Comment: Okay, i will read this tomorow. Thank you so far!